# Get file path from file manager in jetpack compose - android kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want the path to a csv file that user indicate in file manager.

For now it open file manager, but i don't know how get file path from this.

```
@Composable
fun screen(){
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    intent.type = "*text/csv*"
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)

    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ }

    Button(onClick = {
        launcher.launch(intent)
    }) {
        Text(text = "Take a file")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rememberLauncherForActivityResult` function you are calling has two arguments, first one is the contract you want to use, `ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult` in your case, and second one is `onResult` callback that will be called after the started activity is finished. Here you left the callback empty - instead, you should use the `ActivityResult` it gives you. It contains the result code and data - you can get the file path from the data, it will look something like this:

```
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
) { activityResult ->
    if (activityResult.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val uri: Uri? = activityResult.data?.data
    }
}
```

Also, you should check `ActivityResultContracts.GetContent`, which will simplify that for you - using this contract, you will receive the `Uri?` directly in the callback.